# Small object argument for arbirary sets of morphisms

Tags: category-theory, model-categories

I am working through the expository paper by Dwyer and Spalinski on model categories (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/DwyerSpalinski_HomotopyTheories.pdf) and trying to prove the small object argument (Proposition 7.17) by myself. About the setup: one is given a set of morphisms $\lbrace f_i\colon A_i\to B_i\rbrace$ and another arbitrary morphism $p\colon X\to Y$. The aim is to factorise $p$ as $p=p^\omega j_\omega$, such that $p^\omega\colon G^\omega \to Y$ has the RLP with respect to all $f_i$ and $j_\omega\colon X\to G^\omega$ is an inclusion of $X$ into a filtered colimit of $X$ (I hope this is the right term here, what I mean is an sequence $X=G^0\to G^1\to\cdots\to G^\omega$, where each $G^k$ is obtained as a pushout, where one leg ends in $G^{k-1}$). The presented approach is to iteratively consider the sets, denoted $S^k_i$, of pairs $(g\colon A_i\to G^k,h\colon B_i\to Y)$, for which $p^k g=f_i h$ where $p_k\colon G^k\to Y$ and construct $G^{k+1}$ as a pushout of $\sqcup_i \sqcup_{(g,h)\in S^k_i} B_i \leftarrow \sqcup_i\sqcup_{(g,h)\in S^k_i}A_i \to G^k$. Altogether $G^\omega=\mathrm{colim}_k G^k$.

Now I need to show that the morphism $p^\omega$ has the RLP with respect to all $f_i$ if all $A_i$ are sequentially small, that is for any sequence $\lbrace U_k\rbrace_k$ the morphism $\mathrm{colim}_k \mathcal{C}(A_i,U_k)\cong \mathcal{C}(A_i,\mathrm{colim}_k U_k)$ is an isomorphism.

My approach is the following. I want to reformulate the existence of a lift as a property of an induced morphism between Hom-sets. In particular, I believe that a lift exists if the morphism $p^\omega_\ast\colon f_i^\ast\mathcal{C}(B_i,G^\omega)\to f_i^\ast\mathcal{C}(B_i,Y), fi\mapsto pfi$ is surjective, since this essentially states that given a morphism from $A_i$ to $Y$, which factorises through $B_i$, there is already a factorisation of the morphism $B_i\to Y$ along $p$, i.e. a lift. Since by assumption $A_i$ is sequentially small, it should suffice to show that at some finite stage $p^k_\ast \colon f_i^\ast\mathcal{C}(B_i,G^k)\to f_i^\ast\mathcal{C}(B_i,Y)$ is surjective. This is the place where I am stuck. It would be nice to know, if the approach is promising at all and how to go on from here.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find a lift  $B_i\to G^{\omega}$ to the following diagram:
$$\begin{array}
AA_i & \stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow} & G^{\omega}\\
\downarrow{f_i} & & \downarrow{p^{\omega}} \\
B_i & \stackrel{h}{\longrightarrow} & Y  
\end{array}
$$
Now since $A_i$ is small you can find $g':A_i \to G^k$ for some $k$ such that $$\begin{array}
AA_i & \stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow} & G^{\omega}\\
\downarrow{g'} & & \uparrow{j_{k+1}} \\
G^k & \stackrel{i_{k+1}}{\longrightarrow}  & G^{k+1}  
\end{array}
$$
Where $i_{k+1}$ is given in the push-out construction and $j_{k+1}$ and is given with the colimit and then $i_{k}=j_{k+1}\circ i_{k+1}$by construction.
This gives us the following diagram :
$$\begin{array}
AA_i & \stackrel{g'}{\longrightarrow} &G^k & \stackrel{i_{k+1}}{\longrightarrow} & G^{k+1} & \stackrel{j_{k+1}}{\longrightarrow} & G^{\omega}\\
\downarrow{f_i} & & \downarrow{p^{k}}& &\downarrow{p^{k+1}}&& \downarrow{p^{\omega}} \\
B_i & \stackrel{h}{\longrightarrow} & Y &\stackrel{Id}{\longrightarrow} &Y&\stackrel{Id}{\longrightarrow}& Y
\end{array}
$$
This diagramm commutes and thus the first square commute so $(g'\colon A_i\to G^k,h\colon B_i\to Y)$ is in $S^k_i$. So the construction of the push-out $G^{k+1}$ gives us a map $B_i \to G^{k+1}$ which ,when compose with $G^{k+1}\to G^{\omega}$, is the desired lift using basic properties of the push-out.
This is how i would show that your map is surjective!